# AS3 Bottlenecks

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash

What are the common bottlenecks or inherently slow actions/functions that I should look out for while developing an app/game/anything in ActioScript3 and flash?

Comment: This is a really broad question that isn't really specific enough to answer with any degree of detail. One could write an entire book trying to answer this question.

Comment: @32bitkid what about a short list of say the 10 most common ones?

Comment: its probably better to invest in a profiler...

Answer (score 2):

Bottlenecks:

- Exception
- Redrawing
- Big images
- A lot of small vector graphic elements on the stage
- Transparent elements / masks

There are several good practices:

- Use weak links
- Use the `Event.RENDER`
- Store the value in a variable instead of frequent appeal to the fields of an object
- Don't define variables in cycles
- It's desirable to use StageVideo
- If you use Flex be careful with binding
- Be careful with events:

  - Don't forget to remove event listeners
  - Don't dispatch events without need. Especially if they cause redrawing of the stage
- Plus common programming good practices